# Is 名詞 or な形容詞 + ながら a general case?

Tags: grammar

Not sure if this is a noun or a na-adjective but is something like `好きながら`, `貧乏ながら`, `親切ながら`, `貧弱ながら`, et cetera, a general grammar pattern of noun or na-adjective + ながら?

What I mean is, do all these work, or will they always work for a given noun or na-adjective?

Comment: You can't say 好きながら, but can say 読書好きながら. In this case, 読書好き is a noun.

Comment: Where it's grammatical they are nouns right?

Comment: Actually, we can say 読書好きな人, so should we think 読書好き is an adjective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a general pattern. For 好き, it does not work. 好きながら is ungrammatical. It has to be 好きでありながら.

Comment: Now it begs the question of why "it has to be".